# Adding library reference to NewT in CMake CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to make a simple TUI using `newt`. I have installed the newt-dev package: `apt-get install libnewt-dev` and I beleive it is installed correctly since if I do build using `gcc` with following commands, it works just fine:

```
gcc -o test main.cpp -lnewt
```

But my simple code does not compile when I try with `cmake` using new `CLion IDE`. Here are the source code, CMakeLists.txt and compiler output:

```
#include <newt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    /* required variables and string */
    int uiRows, uiCols;
    const char pcText[] = "Welcome to Newt and FLOSS !!!";

    /* initialization stuff */
    newtInit();
    newtCls();

    /* determine current terminal window size */
    uiRows = uiCols = 0;
    newtGetScreenSize(&uiCols, &uiRows);

    /* draw standard help and string on root window */
    newtPushHelpLine(NULL);
    newtDrawRootText((uiCols-strlen(pcText))/2, uiRows/2, pcText);

    /* cleanup after getting a keystroke */
    newtWaitForKey();
    newtFinished();

    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(TemparatureMonitoring)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_library(newt) #this does nothing!

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(TemparatureMonitoring ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**Compiler output:**

```
/opt/clion-1.0/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/saeid/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/9c100db8/9c100db8/Debug --target all -- -j 4
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library newt without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "newt".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: newt
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/saeid/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/9c100db8/9c100db8/Debug
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I think I have to somehow add a reference to newt package, but no idea how! So basically I am looking for a equivalent to `-l` switch of `gcc` for `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: dont really know cmake, but do know that add_library adds an output target, a library, like add_executable. But dont know the solutuion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, after searching a little bit, I think you need the command ''target_link_libraries''
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: OK...credit goes to you! I figured out it works like this: `find_library(libnewt-dev newt)\n
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} newt)`